# Why does (python) gspread work fine from my Mac but fail silently from my CentOS host

Tags: python, http, urllib2, gspread

I'm able to use the [gspread package](https://github.com/burnash/gspread) to update google spreadsheets in a Python script running in terminal on my Mac.

```
gc = gspread.login('username@domain.com','password')
gs = gc.open("Test Google Spreadsheet")
print gs.worksheets()
sht = gs.worksheet("Test Worksheet")
sht.update_cell(1, 1, "Test")
```

When I run the same script from a CentOS 6 host in the cloud, I'm able to to get through the print gs.worksheets(), implying that authentication is not an issue, but I crash on the update command:

```
  File "/mydir/myscript.py", line 30, in myfunc
    sht.update_cell(1, 1, "Test")
  File "my_ve_dir/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gspread/models.py", line 423, in update_cell
    self.client.put_feed(uri, ElementTree.tostring(feed))
  File "my_ve_dir/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gspread/client.py", line 250, in put_feed
    raise ex
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
```

When I use the method for bulk updating cells, it works as expected on the mac but silently fails (without raising any exceptions) on the CentOS host.

```
sht.update_cells(cell_list)
```

So I'm wondering what could be wrong. I make successful API requests (including both GET and POST) to other endpoints, so I'm confused about what could be going on here. Any ideas would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe obvious - are you running the same python version on CentOS as on your Mac? Also did you install gspread the same way on both (using pip for example)?

Comment: You've led me to the correct answer, which is that different versions of gspread were running. Same version of Python was running (with virtualenv), but I'd refreshed gspread on the Mac. Obvious indeed, and yet I wouldn't have thought of it without this post. Feel free to answer it as an 'answer' and I'll 'check' it! Thank you, @orpheist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reposting my answer from the comments - check to make sure both host systems have the same version of python, and gspread.

Also I usually try to use the same package deployment approach on different systems to ensure dependencies are set up - pip is great if it supports the library.